# CSS transition won't trigger when javascript is added

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have three images that slide up from offscreen using transform: translate(). The transform has a 4s transition duration and two of them have delays. Without any script tags (or with blank script tags), the transition works fine. However, when I try to link an external javascript file, or add internal javascript, the transition duration and delays don't work, and the images are translated immediately.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

EDIT: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ginascalpone/pen/ZWVXeX/) -- Doesn't replicate the problem exactly because I can't ever remove the JS entirely, but it does show that the transitions aren't working.

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fake Title</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/mountains-icon.jpg">
    <meta name="description" content="blah blah blah.">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body class="landing">
    <header class="group">
      <a href="index.html"><h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Description</h2></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="mountains" class="transition">
      <img  src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTq/odR/aTqodRXBc.png" id="one">
      <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTq/odR/aTqodRXBc.png" id="two">
      <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aTq/odR/aTqodRXBc.png" id="three">    
    </div>
  </body>

  <script> console.log("Hello World");</script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: sans-serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* Layout Element Colors
=========================*/

body:not(.landing) {background: #7B8784 url('http://ginanicoletta.com/img/laguna-beach.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover; color: #0B0214;}
a, footer {color: #fff;}
footer, nav a { background: #30321a;}
#contact-info a {background: #636362;}
.sample-image:before, #profile-photo:before {
    background: rgba(99, 99, 98, 0.5);}
#contact p a {color: #0B0214;}


/* GENERAL STYLES
=========================*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 74px;
    color: #fcfcf4;

}

li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}


a:active {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/*********************************************
**********************************************
TRANSITION/TRANSFORM CODE HERE
**********************************************
*********************************************/

/* LANDING
=========================*/

body.landing {
    background: #7B8784 url('http://ginanicoletta.com/img/laguna-beach.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;

}

#mountains {
    display: none;
}


/* HEADER
=========================*/

h1 {
    font-size: 2.9em;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

h1, h2 {
    /*color: #0B0214;*/
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}


/* NAVIGATION
=========================*/

nav a {
    background: #30321a;
}

nav ul {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

nav ul a, #contact-info a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px 2.5%;
}

#contact-info ul li {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px 15%;

}


/* FOOTER
=========================*/

footer {
/*  padding: 0 0 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin-top: 10px;*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 74px;
}

footer p {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

footer img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

footer li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.social-icons {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* PAGE: WORK SAMPLES
=========================*/

/*.wrapper {
    padding-top: 15px;
}*/

#work-samples li {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#work-samples div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#work-samples img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}

#work-samples h3 {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    z-index: 100;
}

#work-samples p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* PAGE: ABOUT
=========================*/

.badges {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*.badges li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}*/

.badges li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.badges li img {
    width: 80px;
}

#about img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}

#about p, #contact p {
    margin: 5px 5%;
    text-align: justify;
}

#about {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}


/* PAGE: CONTACT
=========================*/

#contact img {
    width: 25px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/*#contact {
    padding: 5px 0 0 ;
}*/

#contact p a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY: 500PX
==============================*/

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

    body {
        margin: 0 0 77px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }

/*  #work-samples li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45%;
        margin: 0 1%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }*/

/*  .sample-image h3 {
        font-size: 1.05em;
        top: 30%;
    }

    .photo-descriptions {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right:0;
    }*/

    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 1.3em 1%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    footer {
        height: 77px;
    }

    footer img {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    #contact-info {
        width: 350px;
        float: right;
    }

    #contact-info li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }

    #about img {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25%;
    }
}

/* MEDIA QUERY: 700PX
==============================*/

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    #work-samples li {
        overflow: hidden;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #work-samples li p:nth-child(2n) {
        float: left;
        width: 48%;
        margin: 0 1%;
    }

    #work-samples li div:nth-child(2n) {
        width: 48%;
        margin: 0 1%;
        float: left;
    }

    #work-samples li p:nth-child(2n+1) {
        float: right;
        width: 48%;
        margin: 0 1%;
    }

    #work-samples li div:nth-child(2n+1) {
        width: 48%;
        float: right;
        margin: 0 1%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 5em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    footer img {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .sample-image h3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        top: 35%;
    }

    #about img {
        width: 250px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 5%;
    }

    #about p {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

/*  #about {
        margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    }*/
}

/*********************************************
**********************************************
TRANSITION/TRANSFORM CODE HERE
**********************************************
*********************************************/

/* MEDIA QUERY: 800PX
==============================*/

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape) {

    #mountains {
        display: block;
    }

    #mountains img {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: -800px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        transform: translatey(-800px);
        transition-duration: 4s;
        /*-webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
        -webkit-transition-duration: 4s;
        -ms-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
        -ms-transition-duration: 4s;
        -o-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
        -o-transition-duration: 4s;*/
    }

    #mountains #one {
        opacity: .4;
        width: 66%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -10;
        transition-delay: 1s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    }
    #mountains #two {
        opacity: .6;
        width: 40%;
        left: 40%;
        z-index: -9;
        transition-delay: 2s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    }
    #mountains #three {
        opacity: .2;
        width: 33%;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -10;

    }
}

/* MEDIA QUERY: 900PX
============================== */

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    body {
        margin: 0 0 92px;
    }

/*  #about {
        margin: 0 0 70px 0;
    }*/
/*
    .wrapper {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }*/

    footer {
        height: 92px;
    }

    footer img {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        padding: 5px 20px 0;
    }

    footer ul {
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
    }

    footer img:hover {
        width: 45px;
        padding: 5px 15px 0;
    }

    .sample-image h3 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        top: 35%;
    }

    .sample-image:hover{
        width: 90%;
        margin: 10px 5%;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #work-samples li a:hover h3 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

/*  nav {
        height: 42px;
    }*/

    nav ul a:hover {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    nav ul li:hover {
        width: 32%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #contact-info li:hover {
        width: 75%;
    }

    nav ul a:hover, #contact-info a:hover {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }

    #contact-info a:hover {
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .badges li:hover p, 
    .badges li:hover .tooltip {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .left p {
        left: 70px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    }

    .right p {
        right: 70px;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    }

    .badges p {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 10;
        background: rgba(150,150,150, .7);
        width: 300%;
        overflow: visible;  
    }

    .tooltip {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        top: 10;

    }

    .left .tooltip {
        border-right: 10px solid rgba(150,150,150, .7);
        left: 60px;
        top: 10;
    }
    .right .tooltip {
        border-left: 10px solid rgba(150,150,150, .7);
        right: 60px;
        top: 10;
    }
}

/* MEDIA QUERY: 1000PX
==============================*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    .wrapper {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code reproduces your issue? CSS3 should work regardless you have issues in JS (unless JS is taking control over elements style)

Comment: try translateY(-800px). Note the Capital Y.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're right, I was trying to simplify the code to make it readable but it appears I did it wrong. The problem is obviously happening on my local version and I was able to duplicate it on Treehouse Workspaces, but I can't duplicate it in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Giri I've tried translatey(-800px), translateY(-800px), and translate(0, -800px). All produce the same result (works fine without JS, doesn't work with JS).

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing with javascript? it should work. Javascript will not break it unless the logic is wrong.

Comment: @Giri it's in the script tag in the HTML body. Right now it's just console.log('Hello, World!'); but I've also tried linking external scripts.

Comment: @GinaScalpone try moving the script tag within the body tags

Comment: @Giri Sorry, no dice.

Comment: Wierd. can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: @Giri I added it to CodePen (added link to question) but it doesn't duplicate the issue exactly because there's no way to get rid of the JS entirely.

Comment: I see you have translate in the parent element #mountains and then #one has transition delay.  What transition are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Giri Translate is actually on #mountains img, which would apply to #one, #two, and #three. There's also a transition-duration on $mountains img of 4s. #one and #two have delays, which is why they're separated. I've tried adding the translate and the transition-duration each specific image (#one, #two, #three) without success. I've tested it enough that I'm certain the problem is the inclusion of JS.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want the #one, #two and #three to animate when the site loads, if thats what you are trying to achieve, this is not the method to do regardless of the script inclusion. you need to be doing keyframes. If you are using javascript to add or remove a class with translate values, then your method would be right. But you aren't using js to do that.